# Asserting `mocked_function.called` for unittest

Tags: python, qt, unit-testing, mocking, pyside

I am looking to implement unittests for PySide UI and can't figure out how to properly assert that the functions connected to ui elements got called.

So far I've tried different ways to import the module I am writing the test for. Different ways of mocking the function

../app/ui.py

```py
import sys

from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *

def btn1_callback():
    print("1")

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Window, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.btn1 = QPushButton("Foo")
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(btn1_callback)

        layout.addWidget(self.btn1)
        self.setLayout(layout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

../tests/test_ui.py

```py
import sys
import unittest
import mock

from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtTest import QTest

import app.ui

application = QApplication(sys.argv)

class UiTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.ui = app.ui.Window()

    @mock.patch.object(app.ui, "btn1_callback")
    def test_btn1(self, callback):
        QTest.mouseClick(self.ui.btn1, Qt.LeftButton)
        self.assertTrue(callback.called)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Running `python -m unittest discover tests` will run the 1 test and fail saying that the function was not called. It will however have printed "1" to the console so I know the QTest did manage to cause the callback to be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`patch.object` basically modifies what access to the name `app.ui.btn1_callback` resolves to. However, you aren't calling it until *after* `app.ui.Window()` has already gotten its own reference to that function. That reference isn't affected by the patch. You have to instantiate the UI and run the test while the patch is still in effect:

```
class UiTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        p = mock.patch.object(app.ui, "btn1_callback")
        self.addCleanup(p.stop)
        self.callback = p.start()
        self.ui = app.ui.Window()

    def test_btn1(self):
        QTest.mouseClick(self.ui.btn1, Qt.LeftButton)
        self.assert(self.callback.called)
```

Now `startup` is responsible for enabling the patch, as well as scheduling its eventual disabling. `Window()` and the test itself run in an environment where the callback has already been patched.

(Using `addCleanup` is safer than defining `tearDown` to call `p.stop()` because it ensures the patch is stopped even if `tearDown` isn't called for any reason.)